# Angular js interpolation issue when string format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to format the string in the HTML. This is my html Sample

```
      <tr ng-repeat="dob in userId.dobs">
                <td align="center">{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{dob.dateType}}</td>
                <td>{{dob.birthDate}}</td>
                <td>{{dob.dateYear}}</td>
                <td>{{dob.fromYear}}</td>
                <td>{{dob.toYear}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Currently my {{dob.fromYear}}show like 1973/01/21. But I need to split this string and keep only the year. Its like below
{{dob.fromYear}} show like 1973. I tried to do it using below technique

```
 <td>{{dob.fromYear.split('/')}}</td>
```

now my result like ["1973","01","21"]
[image]

I need to display only the year. How i do it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a pipe. Pass the dob string to the pipe and inside the pipe you can do some text manipulation to get only the year.

```
const year = "1111/22/33".split("/").slice(0,1).join()
return year;
```

This code first splits the string. Then `slice(0,1)` picks the year part and `.join()` converts the `[1111]` into a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
dob.fromYear.split('/')[0]
```

But i think this could be problematic if the date is in another format. So better to use:

```
new Date(dob.fromYear).getFullYear()
```